How to Configure Spring Boot to Reject Connections Immediately After Reaching Max Threads/Connections?
I'm working with a Spring Boot application where I want to immediately reject incoming HTTP requests if the server has reached its maximum number of active threads or connections. Instead of placing requests into a queue or waiting for threads to become available, I need the server to reject any new requests once the limit is reached.
Here's what I'm aiming for:

Set a limit on the number of threads (e.g., 1) and connections (e.g., 1).
Reject any new connections immediately, without queuing.
Using Tomcat embedded server with Spring Boot.

I've tried configuring server.tomcat.max-threads, server.tomcat.max-connections, and server.tomcat.accept-count in application.properties, but the requests still seem to be queued and are not rejected immediately.

From the documentation for acceptCount - the operating system provides the queue for incoming connection requests and may ignore this setting and choose a different size for the queue.  With such a small value it may be ignored and depends on the OS.
I'm not sure your requirements but you also may want to consider using a rate limiter library like resilience4jhttps://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter

thanks. we use rate limiter but we want to reject it before it hit the rate limiter
